# Oracle SQL select mutiple columns in one table with same type and make them into mutiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle

i have the following table

[image]

thanks

Comment: not sure why the image didnt show up, please click on the "enter image description here", thanks!

Comment: You should better avoid images, preferring formatted text: text data allow people to build an example and try their answers.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is selecting each of your time columns separately, and then show them together with `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT user_id, receive_time AS time, NULL AS user_message FROM table WHERE receive_time IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT user_id, open_time, NULL FROM table WHERE open_time IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT user_id, finish_time, user_message FROM table WHERE finish_time IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY time, user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your rule for filling and displaying `user_message` the query may need to be altered, but the general rule here would be to get all records for each `*_time` column and use `union all` to put them together

```
select *
from (
  select user_id, receive_time AS time, null AS user_message
  from yourtable
  where receive_time is not null
  union all
  select user_id, open_time, null
  from yourtable
  where open_time is not null
  union all
  select user_id, finish_time, user_message
  from yourtable
  where finish_time is not null
)
order by time, user_id
```

With the `WHERE` clause we don't return rows where a particular time column is empty. This seems to be desired from your output sample.

Comment: when i order by time , it says "ORA-00904: "TIME": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"  regardless upper/lower case, or other variable name. I can order by user_id, but i cannot order by my_user_id if i use "select user_id as my_user_id"

Comment: My script doesn't have "THE_TIME" identifier. Anyways, try to wrap it with `select * from( ... ) order by time, user_id` ;-)

Comment: thanks Kamil for the quick reply, i edited the above comment, let me give that a try

Comment: I've changed my answer accordingly. Seems like Oracle needs a subquery for that :)